# How to create working Basic Authentication in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, iis-7

I used this tutorial to create a basic authentication for my website:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg192997.aspx

I modified the password to admin, however, when I try to access the website in any browser, it always prompts for username and password but **never** accepts it. If I change the code to return *true* on

```
public static bool Authenticate(HttpContext context)
```

It doesn't change anything. What else should I set?

Comment: We need more code. You haven't provided enough detail. There could be a thousand and one things going wrong.

Comment: The code is on the link, I just modified the password string.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that all authentication settings in IIS (for the specific site) are disabled and only Basic Authentication is enabled. Browsers are expected to request a user and password that are always acceptable when they are valid. Sometimes restarting a site and its relative application pool may also help (especially in older versions of windows).

Have in mind that basic authentication is not safe as it passes credentials via a request header in base64 encoding. A good idea is to use ssl - you can get a free one from startssl.com for a live site, or create a self signed one from iis for dev perposes.

Comment: Well, I enabled Basic Authentication on the Default Website and on the WCF Service itself, disabled Anonymous authentication for them and restarted the whole IIS server. The prompt still pops up and I never reach the service.

Comment: Make a simple account (user: abc, pass: 123) on local dev machine and try with this (leave out WFC for the moment). It must work.

Comment: Hmm, if I use my current user with domain\user and password, it authenticates. What does it mean? I just want to accept a simple username and password sent from the client to be authenticated _without_ creating a Windows account for each client.

Comment: If I use the default IIS basic authentication, the browsers accepts my current Windows account as login. If I add my code to the service and try it in the browser, the password is never accepted. I commented out the SSL part of the code, just using the last if `if (!BasicAuthProvider.Authenticate(app.Context))
   {
    CreateNotAuthorizedResponse(app, 401, 1, "Logon failed.");
    app.CompleteRequest();
   }`

Comment: This is not what you explicitly described in your question. In this case you have to use the Authenticate method to control the desired username and password, and in addition to remove/clear the http error using the Application_Error method / or control it with equivalent logic code anywhere.

Comment: 401 will be generated anyway as there is no account. You have to use something like HttpContext.Current.ClearError(); to clear the error in case credentials are the expected.

Comment: I don't understand. I changed the BasicAuthProvider.Authenticate method to return true. The prompt is still there. What are you suggesting? That I have to provide a valid account to make this work?

Comment: Switching to true does not overcome the http error 401. Before switching to true clear the error using HttpContext.Current.ClearError();

Comment: Nothing changed. Did you check the code? My purpose is to access the WCF Data Service with a simple username/pw and if they are correct, let it access the address that provides the data.

Comment: You did not provide your code. Instead you require anyone who want to help to go to other sites and try to figure out what your final code is. I have used basic authentication without accounts in many different cases without a problem.

Comment: I started an IIS Express and debuged my code. It went through the code, and after providing username and password, it worked. So it seems an IIS issue. I enabled the basic authentication on the website and the service but not on the whole IIS server. Should I?

Comment: This is what my answer describes from the very beginning. Good luck.

Comment: I added my assembly as an IIS module, now it won't accept my Windows login but also not accepting the test password. It is strange, that the module update wizard cannot see the dll yet it loads it. So, I am in a dead end.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help. You are the only one who knows what you're doing. You don't provide any code and your descriptions are not enough for the problem you're facing.